# Change Screen Rotation in GNOME/Wayland

Tags: gnome3, multi-monitor

Is there a way to change the screen rotation of a specific screen in GNOME?

I tried `xrandr -d XWAYLAND1 -o right`, but that gives me `Can't open display XWAYLAND1`.

Comment: @don_crissti There's no way to do that in that menu on a Wayland server.

Comment: There has been [progress on this in mutter](https://git.gnome.org/browse/mutter//commit/?id=efef0c993b7e45c1a5d06afffdf302c30ba441a0&utm_source=anzwix). Have you tried this with Gnome 3.20?

Comment: I've just tried this via the gui on Fedora Rawhide, Gnome 3.20 Wayland - the gui doesn't display the usual rotation arrows either.

Comment: `mutter` improvements are targeted for `gnome-3.22` and later

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the screen rotation of a specific screen in
>   GNOME?

Yes, as of [Gnome 3.22](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745079), before that version, Gnome relied on driver support for rotation, only intel drivers support that, iirc. You could try double clicking the display in the Monitor settings menu to access the setting.

You could also [try](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wayland) `<Super>+MMB` where `<super>` is the Windows/Linux key on your keyboard and `MMB` is the middle mouse button.

> I tried xrandr -d XWAYLAND1 -o right, but that gives me Can't open
>   display XWAYLAND1.

`xrandr` is for Xorg, not Wayland.

Comment: While it's true that it works now, it did not work in GNOME 3.22. GNOME 3.22 no longer relied on the drivers, indeed, but did not implement the feature itself.